# jQuery: How to make a field required if two specific options are selected

Tags: jquery-validate

Validating a form w/ jQuery.  For simplicity, user selects from three options: "A_or_B", "C", or "D" from a drop down list.  If A_or_B is chosen then the "Name" field is required.  If C or D, then it isn't.  This was done like so:

```
$("#form").validate({
rules: {
    Name: {required: "#Letter[value=A_or_B]"}
}
});
```

Now I am required to make "A_or_B" into two seperate entries, where either choice still makes the "Name" field required.  How would I change the validation line for the **Name** field now that A and B are seperate entries on the drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but it might be worth a try.

```
$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    Name: {required: "#Letter[value='A'], #Letter[value='B']"}
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like that did it.  Way easier than I thought it would be.  Thanks.